# Plot Distance matrix for a 1D array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to plot a distance matrix plot for distance between 6 towns. A1 to A3 and B1 to B3.

I have calculated the distance like A1-B1, A1-B2....likewise....A3-B3 and I got an 1D array 
I got a 1D numpy array for distance between 6 towns .

```
np.array(R)
[ 3.00  2.50  1.00  3.3192  2.383   2.7128  3.8662  3.6724  3.5112]
```

Now I want plot in an distance matrix format which should look something like as shown in Figure below.

[image: Each cell is colors according to its value.]

it is just a representative data. I got lots of values so need python program. 
Any suggestion or sample python matplotlib script will help. 
Regards.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service - what have you tried so far?

Comment: @SimonGibbons
I know that.
I have got values for different columns in different arrays.
Trying...

Comment: I would suggest showing your code and explaining at what point you are currently stuck. This will make it much easier for us to help you.

Comment: @cel:
I made it. Now working fine. But as I am newbie you may improve the code.

Comment: @SimonGibbons,
Have a look at my answer and you are invited to edit that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you got most of the way yourself. You can clean up your plot to make it a little more like what you intended by changing the axis labels to `A1, A2,...` and by printing the values of each cell within them.

The cleaned up version of your script is below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
R = np.array ([3.00, 2.50, 1.00, 3.3192, 2.383,  2.7128, 3.8662, 3.6724,   3.5112])

# Calculate the shape of the 2d array
n = int( np.sqrt( R.size ) )
C = R.reshape((n,n))

# Plot the matrix
plt.matshow(C,cmap="Reds")

ax = plt.gca()

# Set the plot labels
xlabels = ["B%d" % i for i in xrange(n+1)]
ylabels = ["A%d" % i for i in xrange(n+1)]
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels)
ax.set_yticklabels(ylabels)

#Add text to the plot showing the values at that point
for i in xrange(n):
    for j in xrange(n):
        plt.text(j,i, C[i,j], horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center')

plt.show()
```

And will create the following plot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pylab import *
R = np.array ([3.00, 2.50, 1.00, 3.3192, 2.383,  2.7128, 3.8662, 3.6724,   3.5112])
C = np.split(R, 3)
print(C)
matshow(C,cmap=cm.gray)
plt.show()
```

[image]